# Load view every time when app becomes active

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am making a some kind of password security in my app, so nobody except the iphone owner can open an app. And I'd like to load my password view which I created every time when user clicks on the app icon.

I know there is a nice method in AppDelegate called `-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`. However, in AppDelegate you are not able to use `presentModalViewController: animated:` which I like so much.

How can I load a password view every time, when user opens the app ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why applicationWillResignActive: , its workes at close app? use applicationDidBecomeActive. And you can do something like [self.viewController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the AppDelegate, you will certainly load a view controller somewhere. E.g. a navigationcontroller:

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {


    // probably more code....

    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];  

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;

}
```

now, in this navigationController, you could write a method like

```
(void) lockScreen {

    // code to for presentModalViewController: animated:
}
```

I'd use `applicationDidEnterForeground`

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

    [navigationController lockScreen];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

use nsnotification to do that. add an observer with a method which perform presentation of model view and in didBecomeActive. post the notification.